# vimhelp formatting: escaping backticks within inline backquoted fragments

Tags: help-system

I'm new at writing / editing vimhelp `doc/plugin.txt` files. I've seen backquotes used as a form of quoting literal commands, mappings etc like in Markdown (though `:h help-writing` seems to imply this quoting style is supposed to be only for tags...). Anyway, how do I insert a literal backtick within such inline quotes? For example,

```
This doesn't render as intended:
`<Plug>(XXX-goback)` is normally bound to `g`` (g-backtick)
```

I've tried doubling the inner backtick and backslashing it, doubling the outer backquotes, to no avail. And from other questions around here I, gather there's no comprehensive documentation of the vimhelp syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You were already looking at the right documentation. Vim help is not Markdown, but `:help help-writing` mentions that you can put Ex commands (or any code, for that matter) within inverted angle brackets like below:

```
This is a hot-link using backticks `:yank`
>
    This is inline code with `backticks`
<
```

In combination with `:set filetype=help`, this will conceal the backticks around `:yank` and turn it into a reference but leave the backticks in the code section alone.

Comment: Yes, but that generates BLOCK, not INLINE displays (or whatever the vim equivalent of CSS is). Obviously it can be jarring to have lots of blocks interrupting the flow of text, otherwise there would be no need for inline quoting...

Comment: Technically it's not the backticks that make `:yank` a reference; it'd be `|:yank|` to do that. But `K` and `C-]` work because `K` runs `:help :yank` and `C-]` finds the `*:yank*` tag.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think you are mistaken. In `:help helphelp`, section "TAGS" it says bars refer to help tags in general while backticks do the same for commands. Or did you just a remark on my poor choice of words?

Comment: Ah, I think I missed that paragraph, nevermind then :)

Comment: Huh, I missed these replies. So I *shouldn't* enclose anything other than ":command" in backticks?